# Popup window after the page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Discover Hong Kong!</title>
    <meta name="description"
        content="An user-friendly Hong Kong travel website that provides all the tourist information of transportation, cuisines and attractions to let you explore the best of Hong Kong">
    <meta name="Keywords"
        content="accommodation, Cantonese, cuisines, culture, HK, Hong Kong, service, shopping, sightseeing, tourism, travel, tourist">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

The popup window just appeared for 0.1s and then it's just gone. I don't even click anything and it's just disappear. Here is my code

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    setTimeout(
        function open(event) {
            document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "block";
        },
        1000
    )
})

document.querySelector('#close').addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
.popup {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 450px;
    padding: 30px 40px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: none;
}
.popup #close {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 20px auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #c5c5c5;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.popup p {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
        <button id="close">&times;</button>
        <h2>Coronavirus</h2>
        <p>Before departing , you should pay attention to the relevant boarding, quarantine and inspection
            arrangements.</p>
        <p>All transit/transfer passengers boarding from overseas regions to Hong Kong must hold a Negative result proof
            of a PCR-based nucleic acid test for COVID-19.</p>
        <p>All immigrants must submit a health declaration form.</p>
    </div>
```

I have run the code here and everything is okay. I can click the close button, but it doesn't work in my website.
Someone asked about my framework, so I added the head part of my website.
I have used Icomoon for my icon font but I included in my css.

Comment: Since you've shown that the code here works fine, the issue then is elsewhere in your application. You may want to check for other event listeners or see if anything else is setting the display type of the popup.

Comment: What other frameworks or libraries are you using?

Comment: My suppose: You create the script before your HTML like this `<script>javascript</script><div>popup</div>`. The event of not yet generated element can't work. Put your script at the end of your page.

Comment: @Baro Do you mean put the <script> at the end of the body? I do put it there but there is still no response. You can see that <script> does not include in <head>.

Comment: I saw it wasn't in the `head`, but not necessarily after the `popup`. Without being able to see the problem is difficult, it could be a CSS overlay problem, if your page is online give us the link.